# What file is universal on all OS?

Tags: file, operating-system, directory

I was just wondering if anyone knew a folder location that Windows, Mac, and Linux (If each distribution is different then Ubuntu) all had that could be used as a temporary directory. If each one has their own different one then can someone tell me the temp location for each OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most operating systems allow you to retrieve this from the environment via an [`environmental variable`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). On Windows, for instance, you can see the value for the current logged-in user by opening a command prompt and typing `SET TEMP` or `echo %TEMP%` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Runtime libraries or operating system APIs typically have a function for retrieving the `TEMP` (or `TMP`) folder. In the Windows API, for instance, there's a [`GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Note that the location of the `TEMP` folder changes based on the logged in user on most operating systems. On modern Windows versions, for example, the folder is located in `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp` by default.

So there is no *universal folder location*, but it can generally be found by asking the operating system or environment in which your program is being run for the location of the `TEMP` path.

Answer (score 0):

You should use environment variables on each OS to retrieve temp directory location, as it's not the same even for different users within the same machine, left alone OS.

Comment: Alright, and for Mac/Linux do you recommend using the /temp or the /var/temp folder for a program that will delete what is there less than 5 min after being created.

Comment: You may run into permission issues, so again - it's safer to get it from environment variables.

Comment: Can you expand when you say environment variables? Assuming the computer has a temp folder and if I locate it shouldn't I be able to write to it?

Comment: @maple: Environmental variables are things like `PATH` and `TEMP` (or `TMP`) stored in the system enviromnent, and they exist on *nix and Windows operating systems. Google `environment variables linux` for some links that explain what they are and the basics of using them.